# Need help in implementing a multithreaded service in Android which can queue tasks against a particular thread based on a string

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

So this has me tied up in all sorts of knots.

I'm trying to implement an Android Service which does the following:

1. Processes incoming intents in parallel.
2. Is multithreaded, i.e. has multiple worker threads.
3. Can choose which worker thread to assign the intent to based on a string passed through the intent. So say String 'hello' get's assigned to a thread with name 'helloThread'. And if no thread with the name 'helloThread' is found, then one is created for it. After this point, all new intents with the thread 'hello' must only be processed by the thread 'helloThread'.
4. (Optional) Allows me to limit the maximum number of threads active at any time and if all threads are busy, allows me to queue pending tasks till threads are free to process them.

So far I've tried the following

1. Hacked IntentService to allow me to create multiple instances of the same IntentService for each unique string. That worked, but I lost all lifecycle management which the Android Framework provides. Using my own lifecycle management code proved to be futile.
2. ThreadPoolExecutors, they would work for me if I didn't have the point 3 above as a requirement since they randomly assign incoming intents to worker threads based on availability.

Essentially I need to implement multiple parallel task processing queues.

Comment: `"(I) Hacked IntentService to allow me to create multiple instances of the same IntentService for each unique string"  ` no, you cannot create multiple instances of the same IntentService, Service is a singleton

Comment: Actually it's very much possible. I could link you to the sample code of you like. However, it's still a hack at the end of the day so you're right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` to obtain ExecutorService that will execute your task using only one worker thread and uses queue for other tasks (until previous are processed).
You can use `Map<String, ExecutorService>` then to obtain already created ExecutorService for "hello" String.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. I was able to implement all my requirements.